# Net Connected but Ping gives unknown host - Arch Installation

Tags: installation, archlinux

I am installing Arch on my laptop. I have configured my harddisk and right now I am stoped at installing base and base-devel packages. I am using USB dongle to connect to internet. I am dialing the connection using `wvdial`. Before dialing I configured the `wvdial.config` file and entered all the required parameters in it. My `wvdial.conf` looks as follows:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET"
Password = { }
Modem Type = USB Modem
Stupid Mode = 1
Baud = 460800
Auto DNS = 1
Dial Command = ATDT
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
ISDN = 0
Username = { }
Phone = *99#
Carrier Check = yes
```

When I dial `wvdial` my modem is initialized and is connected properly. However when I try to `ping -c3 google.com` it gives me unknown host. Also when I `pacstrap` the packages are not downloaded saying "failed to connect" message. Where is the problem? I have find a lot on the internet but could not find any solution. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try pinging an IP address (e.g. 141.20.1.33 which happens to be in Berlin) rather than a hostname, that way you will see if it is a DNS problem or a connection/routing issue.

Comment: You are right I got proper pinging when I pinged the IP you specified, But how do I install the base and base-devel package?

Comment: I think you need to get your DNS sorted out before you can do anything because no Internet/web hostnames will work until your DNS is fixed. Look here http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-setup-as-dns-client.html

Comment: What value should I provide in nameserver field. I am using MTS MBlaze USB dongle for connection.

Comment: Google at 8.8.8.8 is good as is OpenDNS at 208.67.220.220

Comment: wvdial gives outputwhich includes two lines primary DNS address 10.228.1.113 and secondary DNS address 8.8.8.8. Then too the problem remains same.

Comment: Can you ping hosts by name now, e.g. google.com, ibm.com, hp.com

Comment: No I can't ping it by name though by IP is still working.